# Visual studio 2015 c++ project creation failed

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have installed visual studio 2015 and when I try to create a visual c++ project it shows "Project creation failed error" at the lower end of the panel, though it works fine with visual c# or other projects.

I have been googling for two days now and have tried tampering with the registry as administrator but it didn't work.

My control panel shows installation of the following:

```
microsoft visual c++ 2015 Redistributable(x86)-14.0,microsoft visual
c++ 2015 Redistributable(x64)-14.0,microsoft visual c++ 2013
Redistributable(x86)-12.0, microsoft visual c++ 2013
Redistributable(x64)-12.0,microsoft visual c++ 2012
Redistributable(x86)-11.0,microsoft visual c++ 2012
Redistributable(x64)-11.0, microsoft visual c++ 2010 x64
Redistributable-10.0,microsoft visual c++ 2010 x86
Redistributable-10.0,microsoft visual c++ 2008 Redistributable-x64
9.0.30721.6161,microsoft visual c++ 2008 Redistributable-x86 9.0.30721.6161, microsoft visual c++ Compilers 2010 standard-enu x64,microsoft visual c++ Compilers 2010 standard-enu x86
```

Comment: What is the text of error?

Comment: creating project 'ConsoleApplication1'...project creation failed

Comment: Hello @AvsenevSlava  will you please help me out there?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after installing the English translations (I am forced by Microsoft site to download the French version).
Switching back the language to French solved the problem. I spent a good 8 hours on this, reinstalling, deleting files manually, etc...

Hope it helps you